Best practice to edit page with foreign keys - send all fields again or just the difference
Let's say I have a web system with Post database table, and this Post can contains Tags, so I'll have the tables: Post, Tags and PostTags.
So Let's say I want to make a CRUD operations on Post, and I want to focus on the Update operation, so let's say I want to make edit a Post, and let's say post has title, description and tags.
There are two strategies that I can think about when editing a post
I can re-send ALL attributes again, or I can only send to backend the diff.
So if for example the current Post is:
{
  title: "A new post",
  description: "Some description",
  tags: ["database", "frontend", "backend"] // this is just for abstraction, but need to make another query to get the tags
}

Now if I edit the page and only remove "Frontend" tag, what should I send to backend?
I can re-send all fields that were used to create and use them as edit, or i can send only the diff (so something like removedTags: ["frotnend"], addedTags: []
What is the optimal strategy? what is usually being used? where can i read more about it and how this topic is called?
